# Where are Received Files from KDE Connect for Android stored?

Tags: kde, kde-plasma-5

When I send a file from linux to android using KDE connect, where are the received files stored? Am I supposed to be getting a notification? If so, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On your Android device you should be able to locate the settings for receiving files by opening KDE Connect:

- Select a paired device
- Select "Plugin settings" from the top-right menu
- Tap on the icon on the right of "Share and receive"

There you will see the path of the "Destination directory" for files received on Android. It defaults to the Android `Download` directory. You also have the option to customize it and turn notifications on/off.

Files shared from Android to Linux appear in your Downloads directory (as determined by Qt's `QStandardPaths` module).

Comment: in german it is "Veröffentlichen und Empfangen" -> Zielverzeichnis

Comment: Also, notifications must be enabled to get info on the phone about a file being successfully transferred.